# Force the Opening of the DataContext's Connection (LINQ)

Tags: sql, linq, connection, datacontext

When you create a datacontext, its connection is closed until you retrieve objects and it stays open when you retrieve objects in case you use deferred operators or late binding.

Is it possible (in an extension method of the datacontext of not) to force the datacontext to open its Connection without querying LINQ with LINQ or doing a fake query to the database with ExecuteQuery, ExecuteCommand, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`DataContext.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.connection.aspx) property to retrieve the connection, and call [`Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.open.aspx) yourself.

Comment: I'll try but will it put the datacontext in an invalid state? Maybe the member functions of the datacontext open the connection if it's not already open, without setting any other flag.

Comment: @Mike: I don't know the details of this, to be honest. I *believe* it is legal though.

Comment: I've taken another approach.. I'll post my article here when done... I'l mark you answer as accepted though.

Comment: Here's what I did (I first tried to use the DataContext's Connection, that's the reason behind this question): http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html
You're a hell of an active guy ;)