# Linq-to-sql context database connection handling

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

What are the rules for how a linq-to-sql datacontext keeps the database connection open?

The question came up when we made a few tests on performance for one `SubmitChanges()` per updated entity instead of one `SubmitChanges()` for the entire batch of entities. Results:

> Inserting 3000 items in one SubmitChanges() call... Duration: 1318ms
>
> Inserting 3000 items in one SubmitChanges() call, within
>   transactionscope... Duration: 1280ms
>
> Inserting 3000 items in individual SubmitChanges() calls... Duration:
>   4377ms
>
> Inserting 3000 items in individual SubmitChanges() calls within a
>   transaction... Duration: 2901ms

Note that when doing individual `SubmitChanges()` for each changed entity, putting everything within a transaction *improves* performance, which was quite unexpected to us. In the sql server profiler we can see that the individual `SubmitChanges()` calls within the transaction do not reset the DB connection for each call, as opposed to the one without the transaction.

In what cases does the data context keep the connection open? Is there any detailed documentation available on how linq-to-sql handles connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't showing the entire picture; LINQ-to-SQL will wrap a call to `SubmitChanges` in a transaction by default.  If you are wrapping it with another transaction, then you won't see the connection reset; it can't until *all* of the `SubmitChanges` calls are complete and then when the external transaction is committed.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a number of factors that could be influencing the timings besides when connections are opened/closed.

edit: I've removed the bit about tracked entities after realizing how linq2sql manages the cached entities and the dirty entities separately.

You can get a good idea how the connections are managed under the covers by using Reflector or some other disassembler to examine the methods on the SqlConnectionManager class. SubmitChanges will call ClearConnection on its IProvider (typically SqlProvider which then uses SqlConnectionManager) after the submit if it wrapped the submit in its own transaction, but not if the SubmitChanges is part of a larger transaction. When the the connection is opened and closed depends on whether there is other activity making use of the SqlConnectionManager.

Comment: The DataContext indeed tracks changed objects, but in the default generated code (by dbml designer in this case) it uses INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged. With those implemented, there is no need to loop through all objects. Anyways you are right that the number of tracked entities grows large.

Answer (score 0):

I messed about with this lately also. Calling `SubmitChanges` 3000 times will not be a good idea, but then depending on how critical it is that each record gets inserted, you may want to do this, after all it only takes 1000ms.

The transaction scope and multiple `SubmitChanges` is what i'd expect to see. Since your still within one transaction i'd expect to see SQL server handle this better, which it seems to. One `SubmitChanges` and using a explicit/implicit `TransactionScope` seems to yield the same result, which is to be expected. There shouldn't be any/much of a performance difference there.

*I think* connections are created when needed, but you have to remember this will be pooled within your provider so unless your connection string is changing, you should hook onto the same connection pool which will yield the same performance regardless of approach. Since LINQ-SQL uses `SqlConnection` behind the scenes, some information about it is at the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx

If your after brute force performance, look at moving into a Stored Proceedure for insert with an  explicit `TransactionScope`. If that isn't fast enough, look at using `SqlBulkCopy`. 3000 rows should insert faster than 1000ms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening and close the connection yourself:
[Force the Opening of the DataContext's Connection (LINQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050940/force-the-opening-of-the-datacontexts-connection-linq)

I think in that case you do not need the extra transaction.